# SCSS variable within @include (Foundation 5)

Tags: wordpress, sass, zurb-foundation, mixins, zurb-foundation-5

Using Foundation 5 and writing semantic grid / column markup through SCSS. To make things simple I divided each WordPress page with `div[role="page/index/404/single"]` and I'm appending the `@include grid-row()` and `@include grid-column()` to the corresponding semantic HTML markup.

I've devised a simple SCSS array to handle my variables in one go but I am having parsing issues.

```
$columns: ( 'article': 9, 'aside': 3, 'full-width': 12, 'none': 0 );

// index.php
div[role="index"] {
    // row
    main {
        @include grid-row();
        // column
        article {
            @include grid-column(columns('article'));
        }
        // sidebar
        aside {
            @include grid-column(columns('aside'));
        }
    }
}
```

I am receiving this error, which I fully understand, but how can I make this work??? I'm out of ideas.

`column("article")/12 is not a unitless number for "percentage"`

If this issue cannot be solved let me know. Would be a pain to manually define integers throughout my code for every site but I'll deal with it if I have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following syntax to access your Sass array (you are technically using a Sass map).

```
@include grid-column(#{map-get($columns, 'article')});
@include grid-column(#{map-get($columns, 'aside')});
```

More info: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/

Comment: It parses my integer but throws the same error: `(Line 32: $number: "9/12" is not a unitless number for "percentage")`. However this information has helped me understand sass maps :)

Comment: Hmm, looks like the values in your Sass map are a type of string and the function requires a type of number. If you can find a way to convert it into a type of number, that would resolve it. Another solution would be to not use a Sass map and just use variables. Ex.

`$article: 9;`

and then use

`@include grid-column($article);`

Comment: That's what I've ultimately decided to do, but I'm disappointed I couldn't get fancier and use an SCSS variable array ... :) oh well.